# How can I drag windows over the panel?

Tags: compiz, gnome-panel, panel, metacity

Basically, I want my windows to go wherever on the screen. I don't want to panel to be a block. How can I disable not being able to drag windows on top of **not under** the panel? Oh, and, yes: gnome-panel.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered autohiding the panel and the setting a show delay so that it doesn't pop up AS SOON as you touch the top?

For the autohide just right click and check autohide from the panel properties menu. For the show delay hit ALT+f2 and type gconf-editor. Click EDIT > FIND and check both boxes. Search for "show_delay" and select the first result. Change the value to anything higher than 100. (I use 700, personally)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the compiz settings manager, go to "window rules"under "window management" and write gnome-panel on the field labeled "bellow" (Note: I'm writing this in a computer with Portuguese localization and trying to translate the terms to English so some names may be slightly different).

Comment: Did this work for you? When I type gnome-panel into that box, nothing changes, even after a 'killall gnome-panel'. Using (type=dock) doesn't work, either...

Answer (score 1):

In compiz-config, go to window rules and add type=Gnome-panel (case is **important!**) in the "Below" field.

Please note that alt+f2 will now be below as well, so add `(title=Run Application) & (type=Dialog)` to above.

Please note this **DOES NOT WORK** in Metacity